# Java: Why does an ArrayList with a referred generic type not count as the cast when calling .readObject()?

Tags: java, casting, io

I am loading an `ArrayList` from a save file which has a generic type inferred, but eclpise is telling me I haven't checked the cast, why doesn't `(ArrayList< TypeOfObject >)` count as a cast when `(TypeOfObject)` does?

```
    game.evilSprites = (ArrayList<EvilSprite>) OIS.readObject();
```

casting the object as an evilSprite works...

```
    game.evilSprite = (EvilSprite) OIS.readObject();
```

EDIT: great, thank you, so it is at least a valid cast, how do I check it to remove the warning?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It does count as a cast, but it can't be checked properly. At execution time, an object has no information about whether it's an `ArrayList<String>`, an `ArrayList<Object>` etc, due to type erasure. So your cast is checking that it's an `ArrayList` of *some* kind, but you could still get a `ClassCastException` when you try to fetch a sprite out of it - the values may not all be `EvilSprite` references.

Comment: thanks, so how do I check it to make sure I don't have problems later?

Comment: @Sebastian: Well, you could iterate over all the values to check that they *are* all `EvilSprite` references... or you could just assume it'll be okay, and live with the risk of a deferred error.

Comment: @Sebastian: Well, it's up to you - so long as you *understand* the error and its implications, you may want to suppress it.